# MySQL parenthesis not balanced

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

How to escape parenthesis or any characters that may break queries?
I am using laravel 5.1 for making queries as:-

```
$books = App\Book::where('name', 'REGEXP', '[[:<:]]'.$keyword.'[[:>:]]')->get();
```

Here is my broken SQL log when keyword contains braces.

```
select * from `books` where `name` REGEXP [[:<:]]Foo (Bar[[:>:]]
```

Comment: Try `preg_quote($keyword)` perhaps?